# How to make an inherited dict class?

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

I am using pypi [dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#dataset.Database) for my db interaction.
It says we can have row of any dict-like class.

Could you just give me a few examples regarding attributes, properties and method inheritance? Especially constructor & distructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find AttrDict useful for quickly creating classes. It uses a dictionary under the hood, so you should be able to pass it to dataset.

Keys of the dict can be set and read as attributes.

E.g.

```
import attrdict
from datetime import date

class Employee(attrdict.AttrDict):

    def get_years_of_service(self):
        return date.today() - self.start_date

>>> steve = Employee()
>>> steve.name = "Steve"
>>> steve.age = 41
>>> print steve.age
41
>>> print steve['age']
41
>>> steve.start_date = date(year=2001, month=1, day=1)
>>> print steve.get_years_of_service()
5555 days, 0:00:00
```

Only attributes (not methods) will be exported.

Answer (score 3):

Inheriting from dictionary is not unlike inheriting from any other type. Consider this simple example: subclass from `dict` without adding any functionality:

```
class Employee(dict):
    pass

e = Employee()
e['name'] = 'Tushar Jain'
```

Add some property getters and setters for easier attribute access:

```
class Employee(dict):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self['name']

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self['name'] = value

e = Employee()
e.name = 'Tushar Jain'
print(e)
```